# Do not board message at the airport check in

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airlines, uae

I have always experienced a do-not-board message when flying to Dubai from Kenya since last year January 2016. Since then I have traveled more than five times to Dubai with a visit visa but every time I check in at the airport with my passport the message comes, "do not board, contact UAE government".

Normally airline staff give me a manual written boarding pass as nobody seems to understand why and how I can have a new valid visa and a return air ticket and my boarding pass can't print.

I have visited all immigration offices in Dubai but no one seems to help or know where the problem comes from. I have never been convicted of any crime of any sort and I don't understand why this always happens to me.

Now I may not be able to travel as the airlines do not issue manual written boarding passes even though I have a new visa issued few days ago and a return ticket.

UPDATE

I have contacted the airline where they have sent me to the UAE immigration and I have done all they ask me to do but none of the two parties accepts the responsibility. Somehow I am wondering why the UAE government is directing the airline to contact them while I try to board the plane and my boarding pass can't print where I have all the correct and valid documents.

When the airline write to the UAE government on email there is no response for days and even weeks leaving me stranded and guessing what's going on. I have verified my visa passport and return ticket with the airline & the UAE immigration but still no help has come forth. I am really looking for any kind of help as this can be traumatizing.                                                                                             Thanx people of good will as I have not received any kind of help from my answer I dint know exactly I need to edit here while replying your messages.

Comment: Why don't you talk to the airline?

Comment: Your issue should be taken up with the UAE government and the airline. Anything you will get from here will be conjecture.

Comment: The airline staff should be able to tell you exactly the reason for the message they display and where the flag came from.  Now why you're flagged, just where they get it.  You then have to deal with that agency.  Could the the Kenyan or UAE Government.

Comment: You may have to get a lawyer.

Comment: May I know what you did to clear your name? I have the same case with you. Im in UAE right now and can't leave the country. Already went to immigration and police but they cannot solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Airlines have no alternative but to comply with a directive from a government, such as Do Not Board, barring a passenger from a flight. The airline is not in a position to resolve this, only the government which imposed the sanction can clarify or lift it. For the UAE, you may want to involve the [Ministry of the Interior](https://www.moi.gov.ae/en/default.aspx), as it is responsible for immigration and port entry.